# why does the scanf for the visanum only work if i enter one character in the first scanf?

Tags: c

```
int main(){

char name;
int visanum;

printf("What is your first name?:");
scanf("%c",&name);


printf("what is your visa number?:");
scanf("%d",&visanum);

if(visanum>=12350 && visanum<=12380){
printf("Your visa is valid please go to counter 4\n");}

else if(visanum>=12300 && visanum<12350){
printf("Sorry! your visa needs to be validated please check with the US embassy\n");}

else if(visanum>12380 && visanum<=12399){
printf("Sorry! your visa needs to be validated please check with the US embassy\n");}

else{
printf("your visa is not valid\n");}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because `scanf("%c",&name);` reads exactly 1 character. Perhaps instead of `%c` you want `%s`, but then you need to pass an array of characters for it to write to.

Answer (score 2):

You need to check the values returned by `scanf`.  More precisely, if you enter "foo" for the name, then `scanf` consumes the `f` and puts it into `name`.  When the second scanf is executed, it sees `oo` and does not consume anything, since those characters cannot be interpreted as a float.  So that `scanf` returns 0 and does not assign anything to `visanum`. Since `visanum` is uninitialized, the attempt to compare it to 12350 and 12380 invokes undefined behavior and there's no point thinking about what happens.

You *must* *always* check the value returned by `scanf`.  In this case, if it does not return 1, the program should print an error message and abort.

Probably, you just want to do something like:

```
char name[128] = "";
int visanum = -1;

printf("What is your first name?:");
if( scanf("%127s",name) != 1 ){
    fprintf(stderr, "Invalid input\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}; 
...
```